# Merge two Python list of tuples

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples. Each tuple contains a datetime object and a float object i.e.:

```
l1 = [(dt1), 1.0), (dt2, 2.0), (dt3, 3.0)]
l2 = [(dt1), 1.0), (dt3, 3.0), (dt5, 6.0)]
```

The two lists are already sorted by the datetime of each tuple.

What would be a fast way to merge the two lists ?

The two lists may not contain the same datetimes.
If one dt exists in one list but not the other the missing value can be `''`

So for example using the two lists above I would like to produce

```
l = [(dt1), 1.0, 1.0), (dt2, 2.0, ''), (dt3, 3.0, 3.0), (dt5, '', 6.0)]
```

I'm guessing maybe I should use a dictionary with the dt as key and then resort but that 
seems wasteful.

Any other ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: How many tuples are we talking about here?

Comment: Why would using a dict be wasteful?

Comment: @wils484: *resorting* would be wasteful.

Comment: number of tuples could be 10000 to a few million i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 = [("a", 1.0), ("b", 2.0), ("c", 3.0)]
l2 = [("a", 1.0), ("c", 3.0), ("d", 6.0)]


i1 = 0
i2= 0
l = []
while i1 != len(l1) or i2!=len(l2):
    print i1,i2
    if ((i1<len(l1))and(i2<len(l2))) and l1[i1] ==l2[i2]:
        l.append((l1[i1][0],l1[i1][1],l2[i2][1]))
        i1 +=1
        i2+=1
    elif ((i1<len(l1)and i2<len(l2)) and l1[i1] <l2[i2]) or (i1<len(l1)and i2>=len(l2)):
        l.append((l1[i1][0],l1[i1][1],""))
        i1 +=1

    elif ((i2<len(l2)and i1<len(l1)) and l1[i1] >l2[i2])or (i1>=len(l1)and i2<len(l2)):
        l.append((l2[i2][0],l2[i2][1],""))
        i2 +=1
```

I think I fixed the edge cases now too.

Comment: The edge cases would be simpler if you just iterated up to the index of the first consumed list, then append the rest of the other list to the result because you know it is already sorted.

Comment: Won't that be less efficient though? If you need to insert a new item it takes O(n) to shift over all the pre-existing items.

Comment: No you would still be doing the same number of appends it would just separate out the remaining part so that it wasn't handled in the if chain inside the current loop. That way the comparisons to see which value (l1 or l2) is bigger only occurs while both lists still have elements to evaluate.

Comment: I misunderstood what you had said. I see that you are now correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful, I used a different approach:

```
result = []
d2 = dict(l2)
for i in l1:
    j = ''
    if i[0] in d2:
        j = d2[i[0]]
        d2.pop(i[0], None)
    result.append((i[0], i[1], j))

for key in d2:
    result.append((key, '', d2[key]))
```

Comment: End Result would not be sorted. And its less efficient... (which is why OP didn't want to use a dict.)

Comment: @Moe good call. I missed that last sentence about re-sorting. I thought OP was indifferent to the order of the merged list.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is about the same efficiency as Moe's answer.  Notice the second value in the tuple in the second list is always placed as the third element in the tuple in the merged list

Result is `Merge_List(l1,l2)`, where Merge_List is:

```
def Merge_List(Left,Right,Merged=[]):
    if len(Left)==0 and len(Right)==1:
        return Merged+[(Right[0][0],"",Right[0][1]),]
    elif len(Right)==0 and len(Left)==1:
        return Merged+[Left[0]+("",),]
    else:
        if Left[0][0] < Right[0][0]:
            return Merge_List(Left[1:],Right,
                           Merged=Merged+[Left[0]+("",),])
        elif Right[0][0] < Left[0][0]:
            return Merge_list(Left,Right[1:],
                           Merged=Merged+[(Right[0][0],"",Right[0][1]),])
        else:
            return Merge_List(Left[1:],Right[1:],
                           Merged=Merged+[(Left[0][0],Left[0][1],Right[0][1]),])
```